Use an RC network to ensure reset on power on
I'm using a DLP-RFID2 module. In my initial design I was running out of GPIO so I didn't connect the RESET line. The datasheet does not say it is mandatory.
Unfortunately the module does not respond to any serial command until I short RESET with GND with a tweezers.
Looking at the schematic in the link provided it seems there is a 47k pull-up resistor on RESET line:

so I thought to use it to form an RC network to keep the line low enough at power on. I placed a 10u capacitor between pins 3 and 4. Looking with an oscilloscope it seems it works:

The cyan curve is the +3.3V power rail and the yellow one the RESET line.
The MSP430F2370 datasheet the RESET should be low for at least 2 us and the minimum voltage to detect a positive value is 1.35V.
The picture shows it stays below 1.35V for almost 200 ms. Still it is not enough to make the module to answer to serial commands. I need to short again the RESET line with a tweezers to make it to work.
Is there anything wrong in my analisys?
Is there a better way to provide a proper reset without adding another wire?

An RC network is a (rather poor) way to provide a /RESET signal.
A better way is to add a chip such as MAX809. There are many variants (reset high/low, open drain vs. push pull and voltage selection). It is multiple-sourced (not just the original Maxim) and not expensive.
In your case you could use a push-pull active low output with a voltage of somewhat less than your Vdd. To be fully effective, the minimum trip point with Vdd decreasing should be greater than the minimum voltage your circuit can operate properly at, and the release point on the way up should be less than the minimum voltage seen on Vdd (with all tolerances taken into account). If that's not possible, you can't guarantee a proper reset.
Even if you get the RC network to work, it does not provide a clean signal, it does not reliably emit a /RESET pulse during brief glitches in Vdd and it does not provide a minimum width pulse to guarantee reset. Further, it won't reset if the power is brought up slowly. It may be acceptable in some applications like cheap toys where the user can switch the circuit on and off again to get it to work. A diode to Vdd can help discharge the capacitor. But again, it's not recommended.

I can concur with Speff's answer. Reset function is best handled by one of these reset chips. Any short cut for power up reset will be unreliable.

+1. I've been bitten by this the hard way. Modern microcontroller have quite strict reset requirement, fail them and you have a piece of useless silicon dissipating power.

I can't speak to the world of chips on a PCB, but I can speak to the world of microelectronics on one chip.
Back in the 1990s I designed BiCMOS for first Signetics Corp. and then Philips Semiconductor. We didn't have the privilege of adding another chip to the circuit. In fact, we were strictly limited to what we could build on the chip — and capacitors of any meaningful size were pretty expensive acreage because the only way to make them was a big field of polysilicon gate material.
When it wasn't important, we solved the problem with a small PMOS device with the gate connected to VCC. The result was an open gate to ground as VCC started to ramp up, holding the RESET line low until VCC rose to a point where the gate would close, leaving the RESET line available for use by the user.
Why did I say all this when you're dealing with chips on a PCB?

I'm not just surprised, I'm shocked that the DLP-RFID2 chip doesn't self-reset on power up. It was old tech when I was taught to do it in the 90s and the on-silicon cost is negligible compared to the rest of the circuit. So, I'd contact the manufacturer and ask why it doesn't.

An RC circuit, as @Spehro says, is a poor solution — but it works. If you're experimenting (as in, you're not designing a production circuit), it's fine. You just want an RC time constant that's a good 60% of the duty cycle of your circuit or, said another way, you want to use as much time before the first legitimate signal you can because you want that resistor to be as large as possible without forcing you to use a cap the size of a Buick's engine beside it.

If you're designing a production circuit, then either using a power-on-reset chip is superior, or simply using a PMOS transistor as I described.



Thanks for the interesting information. I'm going in production adding the RESET line to my MCU, so I can reset the DLP-RFID2 anytime (I also discovered it hangs if it receives a wrong message on the UART - the manufacturer says: "please be sure to send only valid messages")

The RC network was just a trial to save the prototypes without soldering a wire across the board. I was surprised why it does not reset the internal MSP430 even if the signals seem ok.

The data sheet is utterly vague on this.
Not all chips with are level sensitive, don't have a schmitt trigger, and the thresholds are not given.
But the datasheet does mention that no matter if supplies go up slowly or down slowly, the module must not run and must be set into reset if voltage is below the level given in data sheet.
So there is more evidence that it is not a good idea to simply use an RC circuit on reset. It does not protect from supplies dropping.

The reset signal should be a nice clean edge, similar to your voltage rail trace.  The cap on the reset line is a very slow rising edge, and can cause the chip reset pin to oscillate as it passes through the transition region.  As you slow it down more for a longer reset this will only get worse and can cause the chip to go into an unknown (inoperable) state.  Also, if your power has glitches at turn on, the cap won't reset time for those.
It is much much better to use a reset supervisor chip, which will produce a nice square reset pulse for Power On Reset (POR), Brown Out Reset(BOR) etc.

I was expecting a schmitt-trigger input circuit also for RESET, like for the other GPIOs. Otherwise how to explain the table at page 21 in the linked datasheet of the MPS430?

@Mark looks like the datasheet doesn't explicitly state what the reset pin's hysteresis specs are, only voltage and time.  Have you turned on the BOR and POR bits inside the chip?

I can't. The MPS430 is inside the module DLP-RFID2! Exactly, there is an hysteresis on voltage, so it cannot oscillates when the voltage rises up.

@Mark Don't mistake a missing spec for compliance.  The chip may well work with your reset signal if POR and BOR are on.  But since you can't confirm that they are, and it is behaving like they are not, then you have to assume they are not -- and use an external reset supervisor chip.

I got the hint, but I don't understand why POR and BOR are important here. We're talking about the external reset. The POR should reset the MCU on power up and BOR if the power rail drops below a threshold. Sorry, but I don't understand how they matter with the RST input pin

The POR and BOR would negate the need for an external reset to get the chip to operate properly under most conditions. But since your module is not behaving unless you manually reset it after power on, the built-in POR is most likely not set. Thus you are manually creating a POR via the reset pin.

You may need Reset supervisor as @Spehro mentioned. But it may not enough for your scenerio because reset supervisors generally generate reset signal according to power domain they feed from. But if the time period of reset signal they produce is enough for you then you may use them.
I can't see the whole schematic but I hope you use de-coupling capacitors around the MCU. I also don't understand exactly what you want. Do you want to revise the circuit or are you just looking for a workaround?
If you are looking for workaround; you may need some components like timers/counters to generate reset signal logically (or again reset supervisor/monitor). Otherwise; you probably need to update your Schematic and PCB Layout. But for test purposes you may use these components to generate reset signal.

I'm just trying to understand why if the module requires just 2 us with RESET below 1.35V and I provide almost 200 ms it does not actually reset. Indeed, the solution is to add a wire to my MCU, without adding other components.
